# Mysql UNION as a subquery with an alias field

Tags: mysql, subquery, union

I have a UNION query as bellow (I have simplified my working query so it is easier to read) :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT `tableA`.`Store Name` FROM `tableA` UNION SELECT DISTINCT `tableB`.`Store Name` FROM `tableB`) t
```

This works fine and results in a single number with column name COUNT(*)

I want to get this value as another column in another query so I do :

```
SELECT DISTINCT `tableC`.`id as PID,
(SELECT count(*) from (SELECT DISTINCT `tableA`.`Store Name` FROM `tableA` UNION SELECT DISTINCT `tableB`.`Store Name` FROM `tableB`) t) AS noofstores
WHERE
.....;
```

But it wont work! What am I doing wrong? This is part of a bigger query, and all the other subqueries work fine when I do

```
,
(SELECT .... ) AS column_name
,
```

Sorry for poor error description. Update :
This is my full query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
`tableC`.`id` as PID,
(SELECT count(*) 
from 
(SELECT DISTINCT `tableA`.`Store Name` FROM `tableA` WHERE  `tableA`.`id` = PID 
 union 
 SELECT DISTINCT `tableB`.`Store Name` FROM `tableB` WHERE  `tableB`.`id` = PID) t) AS mycolumn_name
 FROM 
 `tableC`
```

Looks like I had the union right and all, but the problem is the PID I am reffering to in the union :

## 1054 - Unknown column 'PID' in 'where clause'

So how do I solve this?

Comment: Pls provide an exact error message, not just that it does not work! In your sample query you are missing the `from` clause, but I guess that's just an issue with the sample code. The point is: without exact error message and full query, it is impossible to tell what may have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The PID column does not exist in the inner subquery, only in the outer query. Either you do an inner join in both of the queries in the union on tableC and do the filtering there, or you need to return the id column in the union queries and join the PID on them to do the filtering.

```
select tableC.id as PID, count(distinct storename) 
from
    (select distinct id, storename from tableA
     union
     select distinct id, storename from tableB) t1
inner join tableC on t1.id=tableC.id
group by tableC.id
```

Comment: I want to count select distinct the storename only, the query above counts the id

Comment: Updated the count() function, this should take care of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join thos two tables to get the result

```
  SELECT DISTINCT c.id as PID from  table C inner join 
        (SELECT count(*) from 
(SELECT DISTINCT `tableA`.`Store Name` as st 
 FROM `tableA` UNION  SELECT DISTINCT `tableB`.`Store Name` as st
    FROM `tableB`) t on t.some_id=c.id WHERE
```